# I'd like to include some content from a wordpress blog in just one section of my html page

Tags: html, wordpress

What is the best way to include wordpress content on JUST A PART of a static HTML page?

In other words - I have an HTML page with a section that I would like to have populated with content from a wordpress site, but I don't want or need the whole page to be a wordpress page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page with the slug "static". Then add a file to your template named "page-static.php". Add the static content to this file and use http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to get the Wordpress content.

Comment: Cool man - I'll work on it and let you know how it works out! THanks!